# HTML renders &quot;

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Hello I haven't touched my clients webpage for some time and a week ago a problem started happening when it called the item description and size from the POST. It started displaying " instead of the regular quotations. Does anyone have any experience with this?[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit - do you mean you are making a cart update, receiving that `response.cart` and finding quoted data in that?  Can you put both the POST data and json response data here perhaps?

Comment: I actually got an email from craft support saying that something in my template is double outputting HTML so i guess i have to go and find that